# GWT CellTable selection and single click on CheckBoxCell

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable, gwt-2.2

I've got a CellTable wich work with SingleSelectionModel to make single selection and show some information into details panel. Also I've got CheckBoxCell column into this CellTable which work with another MultipleSelectionModel to make mass delete operation.

When I try to click on check box in CheckBoxCell column GWT selects row and after second click on checkbox it change checkbox state. So we should make two clicks, but I need to do it (change checkbox state) by one click.

I tried different ways to fix it:

- Change dependsOnSelection and handlesSelection parameters into CheckboxCell
- Change SelectionEventManager in CellTable (DefaultSelectionEventManager.createCheckboxManager(), DefaultSelectionEventManager.createCustomManager)

But it doesn't work.

I found similar problems into Internet but all of them work with one MultipleSelectionModel. It's not the same what I want, because there's details panel (So I could make only single selection).

Can anyone help me to figure out how to resolve it?

**UPD:**
I've just removed SingleSelectionModel and redesigned UI to working with MultipleSelectionModel. It's GWT-hell..

Answer (score 3):

Try to switch your selection models: use the `MultiSelectionModel` as the `CellTable`'s selection model, so that the checkboxes work as expected (with both `dependsOnSelection` and `handlesSelection` set to `true`), and for the master-detail feature, use a `CellPreviewEvent.Handler` (or `DefaultSelectionEventManager#createCustomManager`), and `RowStyles` and `getRowElement`+`addStyleName`/`removeStyleName` for rendering (`RowStyles` when the `CellTable` renders the rows, then `getRowElement` to dynamically update styling).

Comment: Actually I've already tried this way, but it didn't give me the needed behavior. But thank you for answer, I'll try it again at Monday.

Comment: Thanks, that works really well for me using the CellPreviewEvent and testing the event type: `if (event.getColumn() == 1 && event.getNativeEvent().getType().equals("click")) {}`