# GWT celltable combine two click in one

Tags: java, user-interface, checkbox, gwt, celltable

I have a celltable with checkbox. I want to combine two clicks; When I select the row, I also change the state of checkbox. I try the following, but it doesn't work:

```
column.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Item, CheckBoxDisablingCell.CheckState>() {

  @Override
  public void update(int rowIndex, final Item item, final CheckBoxDisablingCell.CheckState state) {
    if(!state.isDisabled()) {                        

    item.getFonctions().get(index).setSelected(state.isChecked());

    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

       @Override
       public void execute() {
           selectionModel.clear();
           selectionModel.setSelected(gestionHabilitationsItem, true);
           cellTableFonctions.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
           leftCellTable.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
         }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

With this code I have two click: one for select the row and another for change the state of the checkbox. How can I combine it? Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: just to clarify, when you write 'two click' in your question are you referring to a toClick event?

Comment: yes two click event with the mouse :)

Comment: ahh i think I we are talking about a double click? So when the user double clicks a row, you want to select the row and toggle a checkbox?

Comment: i can do it with double click but i must do it with just one click event when i select row the chackbox must change the state.

Comment: actually meant 'onClick' in my initial comment when I wrote 'toClick' event . Is this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063273/gwt-celltable-selection-and-single-click-on-checkboxcell?rq=1) any help?

Comment: i tried with CellPreviewEvent bit it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think I got what you need by using:

- `SingleSelectionModel`
- `CheckboxCell` with `handlesSelection` set to `false` (default state)
- `Column` that uses `CheckboxCell` and gets the value from `SelectionModel`

Example:

```
CheckboxCell checkboxCell = new CheckboxCell(); // handlesSelection = false
table.addColumn(new Column<TableType, Boolean>(checkboxCell) {
    @Override
    public Boolean getValue(TableType object) {
        return selectionModel.isSelected(object);
    }
});
```

Every time you select a row, checkbox is being automatically checked. Previously selected row is then deselected (and checkbox unchecked) as it is a single selection model.

[image]

Comment: i tried with this but it didn't work when i click the first time it work but after when i click on another row i must do two click

Comment: @SlimZ, works for me. Do you get any error in browser console? Can you post minimal working example so we can debug it?

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a 'SingleSelectionModel' and checkboxcell

```
  new CheckBoxCell(true, true)
```